# Turing Machine make use of another Turing Machine

Tags: automata, formal-languages, turing-machines

I am expected to formally construct a deterministic TM to compute a function.
I already have a TM for $f(x)$. How can I make use it formally while constructing $g(x)$?

$g(x)$ is like in the followig form
$g(x)=f(x)+1$
let the TM corresponding to $f(x)$ be
$\delta(q_0,1)=(q_0,1,R)$\
$\delta(q_0,0)=(q_1,0,R)$\
$\delta(q_1,1)=(q_f,i,R)$\